# Debugging perl script

Tags: perl, debugging, encoding, sax

I don't know perl, but I need to debug a perl script which is needed by an application I am using, this is the error I get:

```
Unable to recognise encoding of this document at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/XML/SAX/PurePerl/EncodingDetect.pm line 9
```

The thing is, this script cannot figure out what is the encoding of a file. What I am trying to find out is, which file is that. I couldn't be able to find a way to stack trace. Here is the script trimmed a little:

```
package XML::SAX::PurePerl; # NB, not ::EncodingDetect!

use strict;

sub encoding_detect {
    my ($parser, $reader) = @_;

    my $error = "Invalid byte sequence at start of file";
    my $data = $reader->data;
    if ($data =~ /^\x00\x00\xFE\xFF/) {
        # BO-UCS4-be
        $reader->move_along(4);
        $reader->set_encoding('UCS-4BE');
        return;
    } .. tons of if else statements

    warn("Unable to recognise encoding of this document");
    return;
```

I checked, but this reader object doesn't have a name, or path attribute. I have a control over this script, so I may modify it if necessary. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I have tracked down the problem until this line in the application I'm trying to use:

```
my @array = SystemImager::HostRange::expand_groups($clients);
```

Comment: The error indicates that the input XML document does not declare an encoding and the first few bytes of the file don't appear to be UTF-8 or UTF-16.  Is it possible the file is empty?

Comment: I would expect to find filename rather in parser object, than in reader. Another way might be to look around in the code for things like `parse_uri`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [`Carp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) module and the `confess` method, you get a stack backtrace:

```
use Carp;

confess "Something went horribly wrong" if ($something == $wrong);
```

This is of most use inside a function (in a module), but it helps.  However, it sounds as if the error is being reported by code you're using, so you may not be able to get it to `croak` for you, but you should read the manual for `Carp`, which says in part:

> #### Forcing a Stack Trace
>
> As a debugging aid, you can force Carp to treat a croak as a confess and a carp as a cluck across all modules. In other words, force a detailed stack trace to be given. This can be very helpful when trying to understand why, or from where, a warning or error is being generated.
>
> This feature is enabled by 'importing' the non-existent symbol 'verbose'. You would typically enable it by saying
>
> ```
> perl -MCarp=verbose script.pl
> ```
>
> or by including the string -MCarp=verbose in the PERL5OPT environment variable.
>
> Alternat[iv]ely, you can set the global variable $Carp::Verbose to true.

---

As suggested by [daxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46395/daxim) in a comment, also consider [`Carp::Always`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp::Always):

> ```
> use Carp::Always;
> ```
>
> makes every `warn()` and `die()` complain loudly in the calling package and elsewhere. More often used on the command line:
>
> ```
> perl -MCarp::Always script.pl
> ```

---

The pure Perl implementation of `XML::SAX::PurePerl` is marked as 'slow' by its maintainer.  You should perhaps look at using one of the many other XS-based SAX modules, especially one that provides automatic encoding detection.

Comment: [`Carp::Always`](http://p3rl.org/Carp::Always)([`::Color`](http://p3rl.org/Carp::Always::Color))? hijacks all errors to provide a stacktrace, even if the original did not use `Carp`.

Comment: @daxim: Thank you - I've added a link to the canonical (search.cpan.org) link for Carp::Always.

Answer (score 1):

To debug perl script you may use:

```
perl -d:DebugHooks::Terminal script.pl
```

Look at [this](https://metacpan.org/release/Devel-DebugHooks)